# Asp.net Identity - Best way to Extend

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I want to use the New Asp.net Identity 3.0 with EF 7 and wanted to know the best way to extend it. For example if i wanted to add things like User's

- First Name
- Last Name
- DOB
- Twitter Handle
- etc..

What is the best and proper way to do this? I have seen were others have posted you add properties to the IdentityUser and i have seen others who say you should use Claims.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base way to do this, still is to create your own user object and extend this with your properties:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Comment: do you know why others might be saying claims is better? Also i dont need a lot of the feature of Identity on this project so im debating if it would be easier to just use a DBSet and build out my own user and roles tables

Comment: You can store certain data in claims, being: username, roles, ... all data that is used to enhance and make the authentication / authorization faster. But the basic stuff, like firstname, lastname, street, ... keep this in de user or identity object.